# Circular import Python flask (docker-compose)

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, circular-reference

Im getting this error in my flask container while starts with docker-compose up:

```
web_1            | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1            |   File "/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
web_1            |     from presentation.controllers.notifications import notifications_router
web_1            |   File "/app/presentation/controllers/notifications.py", line 4, in <module>
web_1            |     from app.presentation.models.notifications_body import NotificationsBody
web_1            |   File "/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
web_1            |     from presentation.controllers.notifications import notifications_router
web_1            | ImportError: cannot import name 'notifications_router' from partially initialized module 'presentation.controllers.notifications' (most likely due to a circular import) (/app/presentation/controllers/notifications.py)
```

my folder structure is:
[image]

if i run this outside docker-compose it works normally, but in docker-compose it gives an error, does anyone know how to fix it?

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq
      - nginx

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MONGO_URI="mongodb://admin:admin@mongodb:27017/"
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN=true
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=admin
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=/
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
  
volumes:
  mongodb_data: 
  rabbitmq_data:
```

app.py

```
from app.infrastructure.server import entrypoint

app = entrypoint.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

entrypoint.py

```
from flask import Flask

from app.infrastructure.server import url_mapping


def start():
    """
    Starts the application

    Returns:
        Flask: Flask application
    """
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
    url_mapping.map_routes(app)
    app.app_context().push()
    return app
```

url_mapping.py

```
from flask import Flask

from app.presentation.controllers.notifications import notifications_router
from app.presentation.controllers.ping_ctr import ping_router


def map_routes(application: Flask) -> None:
    """
    Map routes

    Args:
        application (Flask): Flask application
    """
    application.register_blueprint(ping_router)
    application.register_blueprint(notifications_router)
```

Can someone help with this? tks!

Comment: Dockerfile:


FROM python:3.11-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers

RUN pip install poetry

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi

COPY app /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]

Answer (score 0):

look at your `app.presentation.models.notifications_body` file

```
from app.presentation.models.notifications_body import NotificationsBody
```

looks like over there is imported something from app.py

```
File "/app/app.py"
```

if it don't help then pls add Dockerfile to the description of your question

Comment: Dockerfile:


FROM python:3.11-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers

RUN pip install poetry

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi

COPY app /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python", "app.py"]